# mytoolkit:FixedHtmlBlock changing styles, xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mytoolkit

So I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 app, and I'm using mytoolkit:FixedHtmlBlock to display html content. My code is below

`<mytoolkit:FixedHtmlTextBlock Html="{Binding Content}" FontSize="24"  Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}" />`

I want to customize the styles of the h3 tags, I found this documentation here https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HtmlTextBlock

It says we can use the following code to customize styles

`((ParagraphGenerator)((HtmlTextBlock)html).Generators["h2"]).FontSize = 26;
((ParagraphGenerator)((HtmlTextBlock)html).Generators["h3"]).FontSize = 20;
((ParagraphGenerator)((HtmlTextBlock)html).Generators["h3"]).FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;`

But I can't figure out how to use these, or where to put them. Could someone tell how to use these codes?

**Update:**
So the `<mytoolkit:FixedHtmlTextBlock x:Name="pcd" Html="{Binding Content}" FontSize="24"  Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}" />` is in a resourcedictionary given below stored in Views/DataTemplates/Post1Detail.xaml.

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="Posts1DetailLayout">
    <Grid Margin="10,5,5,5">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>

                <mytoolkit:FixedHtmlTextBlock Html="{Binding Title}" FontSize="32" Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}"/>
                <mytoolkit:FixedHtmlTextBlock x:Name="pcd" Html="{Binding Content}" FontSize="24"  Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}" />

            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Resource dictionary is accessed in Views/Posts.xaml as

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}">
     <phone:Pivot Name="Container" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}" Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                TitleTemplate="{StaticResource AppPivotTitle}"
                HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AppPivotHeader}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Posts1DetailLayout}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">

    </phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Note that the resource dictionary data template 'Post1DetailLayout' is being used in `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Post1DetailLayout"}`

In PostsDetail.xaml constructor I tried doing the following

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

using MyToolkit.Paging;

using AppStudio.Data;
using AppStudio.Services;
using MyToolkit.Controls;
using MyToolkit.Controls.HtmlTextBlockImplementation.Generators;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.IO;



namespace AppStudio
{
    public partial class PostsDetail
    {
        private bool _isDeepLink = false;


    public PostsDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pcd.Generators["h3"] = new ParagraphGenerator()
        {
            FontSize = 26,
        };
    }
```

I get an error "The name pcd does not exist in the current context". Now how do I access the fixedhtmltextblock name in the resource dictionary and use it in the PostDetail constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mytoolkit:FixedHtmlTextBlock x:Name="YourHtmlBlock" Html="{Binding Content}" FontSize="24"  Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}" />


YourHtmlBlock.Generators["p"] = new ParagraphGenerator()
{
//change properties here :)
};
```

If you want to change more you can make custom ParagraphGenerator.

Comment: Where do I use 
YourHtmlBlock.Generators["p"] = new ParagraphGenerator()
{
//change properties here :)
};
In the .xaml.cs file of the page? and if it is any assembly reference that needs to be added?

Comment: If possible could you give me detailed instructions?

Comment: Put it after Initialization in page constructor.

Comment: Did that this is the error I get `The type or namespace name 'ParagraphGenerator' could not be found`

Comment: I'm having a bit more problems. I have posted an update to my question above, please check it.

Comment: Ok but what about the "The name pcd does not exist in the current context" error?